# How to vertically scroll content on overflow?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, tailwind-css

I have a div where if the content overflows horizontally by default. How can I make it scroll vertically. Here is my html(I am using tailwind)

```
<section class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
    <div class="w-full sm:w-3/4 lg:w-3/5 py-20 flex flex-col gap-y-10 items-center justify-center px-10">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/35/000000/add--v2.png" class="cursor-pointer mr-4" />
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="flex-1 border-0 outline-none placeholder-gray-600 text-4xl">
        </div>
        <textarea name="article" rows="10" placeholder="Tell your story..." class="flex-1 border-0 outline-none placeholder-gray-600 text-2xl w-full h-auto" id="input-html"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full sm:w-1/4 lg:w-2/5 border-l-4 border-gray-400 p-5 overflow-y-scroll" id="output-html"></div>
```

The problem is that the second div just scrolls **horizontally*. And not vertically.

How can I do it vertically?

Answer (score 1):

overflow-y-scroll -> try adding this class to the div.

Comment: That class is added to the *second *child of the parent element. Where do I add that?

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Found the issue @Tyler2P

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out about the issue. The problem was that I was typing some stupid letters in it like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Which caused it to **not** overflow along the y axis. After I wrote some meaningful **space separated** content in it, it worked !

So never write dumb things in your textarea.